# How can you trigger a throw instruction after a certain time?

Tags: node.js

**Problem:** A library function is called, which sometimes does not work. If this function does not work, it sometimes happens that it does not return an error message but is stuck in an infinite loop.

**Idea:** My idea now would have been to use a timer, which executes a throw instruction after a given time, if the function has not been completed successfully before.
If the function was successfully completed, before the end of the timer, the timer should simply be closed.

**Not working example code:**

```js
var errorCounter = 0;
async function a(m) {
  try {
    var myVar = setTimeout(function () {
      throw console.log('Error');
    }, 60000);
    await libraryFunction(m);
    clearTimeout(myVar);
  } catch {
    errorCounter++;
    console.log(errorCounter);
  }
}
```

Comment: If `await libraryFunction(m)` it's gonna error out, it gonna go in the catch block, so you don't need any timeout to do that, that's why you have the `try catch`

Comment: you can't exit an infinite blocking loop (like `while(true){}`) because your timeout function is not executed. You may fix the module or use a `child_process` to isolate the execution

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Promise.race` to simulate a timeout (play with the numerical values below):

```js
const timeout = new Promise((_, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('timeout')), 1000);
});

const task = new Promise((resolve, _) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('done'), 2000);
});


Promise.race([timeout, task])
  .then((result) => { console.log(result); })
  .catch((err) => { console.log(err.message); });
```

So in your case, it would look something like this:

```
const timeout = new Promise((_, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('timeout')), 60 * 1000);
});

var errorCounter = 0;
function a(m) {
  Promise.race([timeout, libraryFunction(m)])
    .then((res) => { console.log(res); })
    .catch((err) => {
        errorCounter++;
        console.log(errorCounter);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) for this type of thing:

```js
const MAX_WAIT_TIME = 500

const libFn = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('success'), Math.random() * 1000);
})

const throwFn = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => reject('failure'), MAX_WAIT_TIME);
})

;(async () => {
    const result = await Promise.race([libFn, throwFn])

    console.log('done') // this line won't execute if the timeout is reached
})()
```